# Loading pictures in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, image

I am developing an application which requires a picture to be displayed. If i run my application from eclipse using the following code

`Image icon = ImageIO.read(new File("src/pci1.png"));`

then the image will load but it wont display when my runnable jar is executed.

If i use this code

```
`String imgName = "pic1.png"; 
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(imgName); 
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(in)); 
icon = img.getImage();`
```

then the image wont display when i run it in eclipse but displays fine when using the runnable jar. I cant seem to find a solution where as it runs in both eclipse and my runnable jar.

Any ideas would be much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that eclipse is assuming your base directory is the project directory, so it happily follows `src/pic1.png` and finds the file. The jar file assumes the directory that it's being run in is the base directory.

Normally, you wouldn't pack a folder called `src` into your jar... just the packages contained therein. It's good style to keep your graphics, configuration, etc, in a `resources` folder that is packed into the jar instead.